# nth-last-of-type CSS selector with unexpected behavior

Tags: css

I need the tag "li" with Text "Should not be selected" no selection, but is selected.

The CSS was so

```
ul ul li:nth-last-of-type(2){
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

The HTML was so

```
<ul>
  <li>bla
    <ul>
      <li>bla bla
      <ul>
        <li>Selected</li>
        <ul>
          <li>Should not be selected</li>
          <li>bla bla bla bla</li>
        </ul>
        <li>bla bla bla</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Selected</li>
      <li>bla bla</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>bla
    <ul>
        <li>Selected</li>
        <li>bla bla</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>bla
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS logic you're using is wrong. Using the "greater than" symbol (`>`) means you're selecting a direct child, and in this case, the markup does not match.

To achieve what you want, the correct CSS rule would be:

`ul ul ul ul > li:nth-last-of-type(2){
  background: #ff0000;
}`

I **MUST** say this does not seem like a maintainable CSS code, and would advise against it. I'd recommend the use of classes for the `li` item, or if you need it to be dynamic, at least give a class to the `ul` to target easily.

I'd recommend a quick read about **CSS Specificity**, [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) or [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: Regarding the wrong logic, was typing error.
Yes, it needs to be dynamic. How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector will select every `li` which is 2nd last `li` in its `ul` container and has *at least one* more `ul` ancestor. The 1st inmost `li` fits this requirement (despite the ivalid bit of markup there, `ul` can't be child of `ul`).

If you want to select items only on the 3rd nesting level, but not deeper, the easiest option is just to restore the styles for deeper nested `li`s:

```
ul ul > li:nth-last-of-type(2){
  background: #ff0000;
}
ul ul ul > li:nth-last-of-type(2){
  background: initial; /* or reset to default LI background value */
}
```

But I agree with **Johnny Kutnowski** that such code is hard to maintain. I'd suggest to use different classes for lists that require special styling.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted him to have a more generic behavior. If I add one more "ul" the last "li" in HTML, then your "li" should not be selected without having to modify the css. Please note below.

```
<ul>
  <li>bla
    <ul>
      <li>bla bla
        <ul>
          <li>Selected</li>

          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>Should not be selected</li>
              <li>Bla bla bla bla bla</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>must be selected</li>
          <li>bla bla bla bla</li>
          <li>bla bla bla</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Selected</li>
      <li>bla bla</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>bla
    <ul>
        <li>Selected</li>
        <li>bla bla</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>bla</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The solution would be this: 
ul ul ul ul ul> li: nth-last-of-type (2) {
  background: initial; 
}
But i did not want do this. If I add another ul down the hierarchy I will have to add a ul in css thereby making.
ul ul ul ul ul ul> li: nth-last-of-type (2) {
  background: initial;
}